# ORACLE SQL select between days, show each day in a new column

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot, infragistics

it is possible in ORACLE SQL, for each day between 2 dates, to get an "own select" with the respective date.

```
SELECT 
    TO_CHAR('01.09.2022') AS DATE1 
  , TO_CHAR('02.09.2022') AS DATE2
  , TO_CHAR('03.09.2022') AS DATE3
 FROM 
    DUAL
```

As an example I select from two comboboxes two different dates = 01.09.2022 & 03.09.2022

Now I want to see these dates not in a column with several rows, but each day in a row with several columns.

Background, and maybe it is also a wrong approach. Is to create an "ultragrid" with Infragistics and there I would like to have in the X-AXIS these days with date.

[image: How it should look like]

Comment: Please show the result you want to get. It is not clear what "**each day in a row** with several columns" means. If each day is a separate row, then what should be the columns? Or if each day is a separate column in a row, then what should be the value of that column and what should be a "row identifier".

Comment: I want to select 2 different dates (like 01.09.2022 and 27.09.2022). Foreach day between this dates (26 days), i want to create another column with the date name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have expressed myself too unclearly. I have 2 comoboxes from which I take the dates and for each days between these days I would like to have produced a separate select.

I have solved the whole messy in Visual Studio with a subquery

i thought i had to create a "pivot" for each day? i know even less about this.
anyway, the following solution works for now

```
string ret = "";
        System.Collections.Generic.List<System.DateTime> allDays = new System.Collections.Generic.List<System.DateTime>();

        for (System.DateTime date = this.dtp_DATUM_VON.DateTime; date <= this.dtp_DATUM_BIS.DateTime; date = date.AddDays(1))
            allDays.Add(date);

        foreach (var CurrentDate in allDays)
        {
            ret += string.Format("(SELECT TABLENAME.VALUE AS \"{0}\" FROM TABLENAME WHERE GEN_DATUM = TRUNC(TO_DATE('{0}', 'dd.mm.yyyy ')) AND ART = '{1}' AND KEY = '{2}') AS \"{0}\" ,", CurrentDate.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy"), this.tc_Main.ActiveTab.Text, this.str_grd_Selected_Row_Key);
        }
        ret = ret.Remove(ret.Length - 1);
        return ret;
```

to fill the grid for the statistic display i have a hashtable that passes the value to the database

```
SELECT
   TABLENAME.TABLENAME_ID   AS GRD_ROW_ID

 , {GET_DAYS_BETWEEN_CMB}
FROM
   TABLENAME
```

Answer (score 2):

In Oracle SQL (and most other SQL dialects), a `SELECT` statement must have a fixed, known number of columns that can be determined from the SQL statement; it is not possible to have a dynamic number of columns with a static SQL statement.

Instead, what you should do is generate the dates as rows and then pivot the data in your third-party application that is accessing the database so that the date column becomes the x-axis of your dataset.

You can use something like this SQL:

```sql
WITH calendar (day) AS (
  SELECT DATE '2022-09-01' + LEVEL - 1
  FROM DUAL
  CONNECT BY DATE '2022-09-01' + LEVEL - 1 <= DATE '2022-09-03'
)
SELECT  c.day,
        t.green_value,
        t.blue_value,
        t.purple_value
FROM    your_table t
        INNER JOIN calendar c
        ON t.datetime = c.day
```

Answer (score 1):

Even though your aim how to use that is not clear enough, you can generate such a logic through use of dynamic SQL along with **`SYS_REFCURSOR`** by creating a function such as

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION Get_Pivoted_Dates( i_first_date DATE, i_last_date DATE ) RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR IS
  v_recordset SYS_REFCURSOR;
  v_sql       VARCHAR2(32767);
BEGIN
  SELECT LISTAGG('date'''||TO_CHAR(i_first_date+rn-1,'yyyy-mm-dd')||CHR(39)||' AS date_'||rn ,',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY 0)
    INTO v_sql
    FROM (SELECT level AS rn FROM dual CONNECT BY level <= i_last_date - i_first_date + 1 );

  v_sql :='SELECT '|| v_sql ||' FROM dual';

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_sql);
  OPEN v_recordset FOR v_sql;
  RETURN v_recordset;
END;
/
```

and then call the created function from SQL Developer's console as

```
SQL> DECLARE
    result SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
   :result := Get_Pivoted_Dates( date'2022-09-04', date'2022-09-06' );
END;
/

SQL> PRINT result;

DATE_1      DATE_2      DATE_3
---------   ---------   ---------
4.09.2022   5.09.2022   6.09.2022
```

where *three* columns are produced as the interval between the dates has *three* dates in this case.